# Add features to Prestashop email order confirmation

Tags: php, prestashop, prestashop-1.6

I want to add product features to order confirmation send to customer in Prestashop.

In that case in 1.6.1.4 class/PaymentModule.php file we have, and it show us **Product name - Attribute: Attribute Value** like **Nice Nike shoes - Size: 42**.

I want to extend it to show also:

**Nice Nike shoes - Size: 42**

**Series: Hyperdunk** (as feature Series and feature value Hyperdunk)

```
 'name' => $product['name'].(isset($product['attributes']) ? ' - '.$product['attributes'] : ''),
```

So i want to add new template variable like

```
  'features' => $product['features'].(isset($product['features']) ? ' - '.$product['features'] : ''),
```

Also in order_conf_product_list.tpl i add

```
<td style="border:1px solid #D6D4D4;">
    <table class="table">
        <tr>
            <td width="10">&nbsp;</td>
            <td>
                <font size="2" face="Open-sans, sans-serif" color="#555454">
                    <strong>{$product['name']}</strong><br />{$product['features']} 
                </font>
            </td>
            <td width="10">&nbsp;</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</td>
```

But it not working... Any ideas?

**EDIT:** After enable debug mode on i have Array - Array in place of {$product['features']} variable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, your change in PaymentModule is not correct.
The `$product['features']` only contain an array with the `id_feature`, `id_product` and `id_feature_value`.
You need to get the features name and value, before the assignment to the tpl, with:

```
$features = "";
if($product_features = Product::getFrontFeaturesStatic($order->id_lang, $product['id_product'])){
     foreach($product_features as $f){
          $features .= $f['name'] . " - " . $f['value'];
     }
}
```

Then assign it to the the template

```
'features' => $features,
```

Or concatenate to the product name.

EDIT (to add condition as requested in comment):

Use the following code:

```
$features = "";
if($product_features = Product::getFrontFeaturesStatic($order->id_lang, $product['id_product'])){
    foreach($product_features as $f){
         if(in_array($f['id_feature'], array(3, 5)))
              $features .= $f['name'] . " - " . $f['value'];
    }
}
```

Comment: Very nice! Need to little tweak with names but it work! Now i see that some of the products have a lot of features... Can You help with the limit of them to show only selected feature name id=3 & id =5?

Comment: I've edited my answer and added the condition to only concatenate if id_feature is 3 or 5. it will ignore others.

Comment: Perfect! Im almost have this solution to. Have a nice day mate! :)